# How to increase superset row limit and timeout cache for SQL Lab and Visualization

Tags: sql, hive, visualization, impala, apache-superset

I have a dataset that has 1 billion rows. The data is stored in Hive. Also, I put Impala as a layer between Hive and Superset. The queries that are run in Superset have row limit max. 100.000. I need to change it with no row limit. Furthermore, I need to make a visualization from what the queries return from SQL lab, but it cannot be done because there is a timeout cache limit also. Therefore,  if I change/increase the row limit in SQL lab and timeout cache in visualization, then I guess, there will be no problem.

[image]

Comment: so you need to increase limit in `superset` or `impala` ? in case of impala, if you are trying to access using hue, you can increase it for other connections/tools, probably there is no limit to # of rows.

Comment: When I run any query in impala, there is no problem. But I need to run queries in superset to visualize the output. ındeed, when using superset, it returns results that just have max. 100000 rows but when I use impala the same queries give me more than 100000 rows. So, superset do not give me the whole result that I need. Furthermore, for visualization in superset, there is also another row limit. It uses only 1000 rows of tables and if the run time of query is above 60sec, it also return error.

Answer (score 1):

i am trying my best to answer below. Pls backup all config files before changing.

For SQL row limit issue -

1. modify config.py file inside the 'anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages' and set

```
DEFAULT_SQLLAB_LIMIT  to 1000000000
QUERY_SEARCH_LIMIT to 1000000000
```

2. modify viz.py and set-

```
filter_row_limit  to 1000000000
```

For timeout issue, increase below parameter values -

For synchronous queries - change superset_config.py

```
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT 
SQLLAB_TIMEOUT 
SUPERSET_TIMEOUT  --This value should be >=SQLLAB_TIMEOUT
```

For async queries -

```
SQLLAB_ASYNC_TIME_LIMIT_SEC
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but we tried what you said and there is nothing changed in the superset. After changing the config file, it looks like a change has been made, I mean it shows a 1billion row limit, but when I run the query, it considers the row limit as 100000 in query history. Therefore, we still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve the problem by modifying **SQL_MAX_ROW** in `/superset/config.py` to the new maximum desired.

```
# Maximum number of rows returned for any analytical database query
SQL_MAX_ROW = 100000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There must be a config parameter to change the max row limit in site-packages/superset, DEFAULT_SQLLAB_LIMIT to set the default and SQL_MAX_ROW to set the max in SQL Lab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess we have to run superset_init again to make the change appear on Superset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

find your superset_config.py, then add those words will solve the row limit question

```py
SQL_MAX_ROW = your_dedired_row_number
```

e.g. `SQL_MAX_ROW = 10000000`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `ssuperset_config.py` (or `value.yml` if using helm)
2. Add the following:

```
SQLLAB_ASYNC_TIME_LIMIT_SEC = 60 * 60 * 6 # 6 hours
 SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT = 3600
 ROW_LIMIT = 50000000
 VIZ_ROW_LIMIT = 50000000
 SAMPLES_ROW_LIMIT = 50000000
 FILTER_SELECT_ROW_LIMIT = 50000000
 QUERY_SEARCH_LIMIT = 50000000
 SQL_MAX_ROW = 500000000
 DISPLAY_MAX_ROW = 50000000
 DEFAULT_SQLLAB_LIMIT = 50000000
```

3. Go to Chart and SET ROW LIMIT to 0.
   It will not come in drop down but you need to write it.
   Check the View query and you can see it is taking ROW_LIMIT 50000000